# Google API Insufficient authentication scope for MySQL proxy on Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-api, cloud-sql-proxy, mysql-proxy

I am having a problem starting proxy for Google SQL.

I installed proxy like this:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64

$ mv cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 cloud_sql_proxy

$ chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

$ sudo mkdir /cloudsql; sudo chmod 777 /cloudsql
```

Problem is when I try to run proxy:

```
$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=myproject:us-central1:mydb
```

I receive error message:

```
googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes., forbidden
```

I enabled Google API as described in documentation. Both 'Compute Engine' and 'Cloud SQL' are in the same project. I expected there will be no need to additional authentication.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: What scopes do you have enabled on Compute Engine? What roles/permissions are assigned to the Compute Engine service account? Edit your question with these details.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Thank you for the suggestion. I managed to fix the problem thanks to it. It was a problem with scopes indeed (Compute Engine > VM instance details > Cloud API access scopes).

Comment: @John-no1 did you only enable the Cloud SQL APi or all?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to John Hanley's suggestion, I fixed the problem.

Issue was with missing permissions for API. I added them here: Compute Engine > VM instance details > Cloud API access scopes. Permission for all APIs was disabled and after enabling them, I was able to successfully run Google SQL proxy.